# insert interpolated zeros into an array of dates in javascript

Tags: javascript

Given a list of values for charting like the below `arrays`

```
var arrays = [["A", [
                      [1391032800000, 20],
                      [1389826800000, 4],
                      [1389913200000, 4],
                      [1390086000000, 6]
                    ]
                ]];              
var dates = arrays[0][1].sort(function(x, y) { return x[0] - y[0]; });
var map = dates.map(function(dt) { return [new Date(dt[0]), dt[1]]; });
console.log(map);
```

The map contains:

[image]

I need to add additional `Array(2)` values into the `map` variable for all the days that are missing between Jan 16 and the end date of Jan 30.

What's the quickest way to fill the missing zero values (for each missing day) in the array.

Comment: Are the times of day potentially all different?

Comment: Where do the second values in each array(2) come from? i.e., the 4, 4, 6, 20 values

Comment: @Darren: No, the times of the day should all be the same, the time component should be ignored

Comment: @David The second values are a given, I have values for 4 particular days. I want to add zeros for all the dates (days) that are not represented.

Comment: I'd do it the opposite of what you're thinking - make the array of dates first (get first and last from your array then fill in the blanks) then loop through that array and map with values in `arrays`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the time of the day is the same and based on Darren Sweeney's suggestion:

```
const data = [
    [1391032800000, 20],
    [1389826800000, 4]
];

// getting min and max dates in the array
const timestamps = data.map(([timestamp]) => timestamp);
const [min, max] = [Math.min(...timestamps), Math.max(...timestamps)];

// creating hash where evrey day in the range between min and max dates has a value of 0
let dataObj = {};
let tempTimestamp = min;

while (tempTimestamp <= max) {
    dataObj[tempTimestamp] = 0;
    tempTimestamp += 86400000;
}

// lopping through the original array and populating a "zero-valued" hash with values from original array
data.forEach(([timestamp, value]) => {
    dataObj[timestamp] = value;
})

// converting a hash into array
const result = Object.keys(dataObj).map(timestamp => ([timestamp, dataObj[timestamp]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getDate` method and then `reduce` method to create new array and get difference between each two dates and fill that difference with zeros.

```js
var arrays = [
  ["A", [
    [1391032800000, 20],
    [1389826800000, 4],
    [1389913200000, 4],
    [1390086000000, 6]
  ]]
];
var dates = arrays[0][1].sort(function(x, y) {
  return x[0] - y[0];
});
var map = dates.map(function(dt) {
  return [new Date(dt[0]), dt[1]];
});

var result = map.reduce((r, [e], i, arr) => {
  if (i != 0) {
    let date = e.getDate();
    let prev = arr[i - 1][0].getDate();
    r.push(...Array(date - prev - 1).fill(0))
  }
  r.push([e]);
  return r;
}, [])


console.log(result)
```

Comment: this solution, whilst it looks great, if you run it, it doesn't show the dates for the missing entries, and it looses the values.

Comment: You said you want to insert 0 for missing days.